# How to replicate this wikipedia plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to replicate the plot linked using Python and pandas.

[image]

The Pandas DF is below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
             {"Sex":["Male"]*8+["Female"]*6,
            "Metabolic Rates":[525.8,605.7,843.3,1195.5,1945.6,2135.6,2308.7,
             2950,727.7,1086.5,1091,1361.3,1490.5,1956.1]})
```

I tried to do it with matplotlib's error bar but does not seem to work.

```
import numpy as np
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
dy = 894.372699158466
y = df.loc[df["Sex"]=="Male"]["Metabolic Rates"]
plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr=dy, fmt='o');
```

I only obtain this plot:

[image]

Comment: Do you want the red arrows to be plotted as well?

Comment: I would translate female to 0 and male to 1 and then generate a series of x and y co-ordinates then plot this as a scatter. Then a second call to scatter to plot the mean. The arrow is trickier and I'd use `annotate` to draw the arrows: https://matplotlib.org/users/annotations.html

Comment: @Andrew matplotlib supports categorical data, no need to translate female/male into numbers.

Comment: @NilsWerner Yes, definitely. I want to replicate the exact same plot.

Comment: @Mr.T I wasn't completely sure whether it was supported for scatter plots, so hedged. Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create the data
mr_m = [525.8, 605.7, 843.3, 1195.5, 1945.6, 2135.6, 2308.7, 2950]
mr_f = [727.7, 1086.5, 1091, 1361.3, 1490.5, 1956.1]
mean_f = np.mean(mr_f)
mean_m = np.mean(mr_m)
std_f = np.std(mr_f)
std_m = np.std(mr_m)

# Create a figure
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

# Set Layout
ax.set_xlim([0.4, 2.6])
ax.set_xticks([1, 2])
ax.set_xticklabels(['Female', 'Male'])
ax.set_ylabel('Metabolic Rate')

# Plot the data
ax.plot(np.ones_like(mr_f), mr_f, 'ko')
ax.plot(2 * np.ones_like(mr_m), mr_m, 'ko')
ax.plot(1, mean_f, 'ro')
ax.plot(2, mean_m, 'ro')

# Plot the arrows and the text with annotate() 
# some tuning on the values necessary to get the right offsets
# annotate() calls FancyArrowPatch to plot the arrows, could be used directly 
ax.annotate('', xy=(1.1, mean_f - std_f / 2),
            xytext=(1.1, mean_f + std_f / 2),
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='<->', color='r'))
ax.annotate('Female\nStd. Dev.={}'.format(int(std_f)), xy=(1.15, mean_f -100))
ax.annotate('', xy=(2.1, mean_m - std_m / 2),
            xytext=(2.1, mean_m + std_m / 2),
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='<->', color='r'))
ax.annotate('Male\nStd. Dev.={}'.format(int(std_m)), xy=(2.15, mean_m -100))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can plot it like this:

```
mean_male = df[df['Sex'] == 'Male'].mean().iloc[0]
mean_female = df[df['Sex'] == 'Female'].mean().iloc[0]
std_male = df[df['Sex'] == 'Male'].std().iloc[0]
std_female = df[df['Sex'] == 'Female'].std().iloc[0]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()
plt.plot(df.Sex, df['Metabolic Rates'], marker='.', linestyle='', color='black', markersize=12)
plt.errorbar(['Male', 'Female'], [mean_male, mean_female], yerr=[std_male, std_female], fmt='o', color='red')
```

More formatting is of course optional. For example plotting the red arrows would require something like `plt.annotate`.

To use the `pandas` functionality to full extent, I'd recommend reformatting the `df`. Using columns or indices is a great way to aggregate data in pandas.
For example you could format your df like this:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame({'Male': df[df.Sex == 'Male'].iloc[:, 1], 'Female': df[df.Sex == 'Female'].reset_index(drop=True).iloc[:, 1]})
```

(I guess there is also an easier way using `groupby` or `aggregate`.)
Now you can easily get the required information like `std` and `mean` for all columns with `df.std()` and `df.mean()`. Also using the pandas plotting frontend is possible.